Creating directories for */.git failed
I used JGit library for cloning and pulling repository in my app.
Git clone code:
Git.cloneRepository()
                    .setURI(remoteURL)
                    .setDirectory(repoDir)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .call();

When I run on IntelliJ IDE, it works, but if running in Docker container, it has this error:
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Creating directories for /app/policyrepo/.git failed
2024-10-22T10:19:02.949264300Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils.mkdirs(FileUtils.java:421) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.10.0.202406032230-r.jar:6.10.0.202406032230-r]
2024-10-22T10:19:02.949265500Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.create(FileRepository.java:231) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.10.0.202406032230-r.jar:6.10.0.202406032230-r]
2024-10-22T10:19:02.949266700Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:103) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.10.0.202406032230-r.jar:6.10.0.202406032230-r]
2024-10-22T10:19:02.949267900Z  ... 27 common frames omitted
2024-10-22T10:19:02.949269100Z 

I used Jib to build image with config
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <allowInsecureRegistries>true</allowInsecureRegistries>
                <from>
                    <image>${jib-maven-plugin.image}</image>
                    <platforms>
                        <platform>
                            <architecture>${jib-maven-plugin.architecture}</architecture>
                            <os>linux</os>
                        </platform>
                    </platforms>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>vauthz/vauthz-be</image>
                </to>
                <container>
                    <entrypoint>
                        <shell>bash</shell>
                        <option>-c</option>
                        <arg>/entrypoint.sh</arg>
                    </entrypoint>
                    <environment>
                        <SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>ALWAYS</SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>
                    </environment>
                    <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                    <user>1000</user>
                    <ports>
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </ports>
                </container>
                <extraDirectories>
                    <paths>src/main/docker/jib</paths>
                    <permissions>
                        <permission>
                            <file>/entrypoint.sh</file>
                            <mode>755</mode>
                        </permission>
                    </permissions>
                </extraDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

Could someone help me to find out the reason of above error?

Check permissions for /app/policyrepo/.

I granted write permision for directory. This is my entrypoint:
mkdir /app/policyrepo
chmod +rwx /app/policyrepo
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -noverify -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -cp /app/resources/:/app/classes/:/app/libs/* "<APP_NAME>"  "$@"
